# jquery-ui autocomplete does not seem to trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I need help trying to make a jQuery-ui autocomplete function work. My code is as follows:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#sku').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    function: 'skuAutocomplete',
                    data: {
                        skuAutocomplete: request
                    }
               },
               error: function() {
                  alert('An error occurred connecting to server. Please check your network');
               },
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function(json) {
                    if (json.status) {
                        response(json.data.skuAutocomplete);
                    }else{
                        alert(json.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3
    });
});
</script>
<input type="text" name="sku" id="sku">
```

When I start to type in the text box, I don't get any network requests, or any errors in console log.

I have checked:

1: That all the jQuery functions are being loaded, and none of the files 404.

2: That no errors are generated loading the page.

I'm not sure where to go next, I am not sure how to trigger this function, which came from a quick-start guide. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: your code seems to be fine. for some reason, I had to wrap the autocomplete function inside another function, and call that function for it to work, like so: `function runAutocomplete() {// your autocomplete code}` `runAutocomplete();`

Comment: Where do I stick runAutocomplete? in an on-change event in the input tag?

Comment: no you just call it in your javascript

Comment: please see my answer, and tell me if that worked for you

Comment: This didn't fix it for me. It seems like it never fires.

Comment: So the fix was that I was using jQuery to build the form after calling the function. I tried to simplify the code for here, and ended up editing out my mistake. Thanks for the help, you did solve the function issue too so ill mark that answer correct.

Comment: *"So the fix was that I was using jQuery to build the form"* - such information and code is not present in question... voting to close as no repro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and this seemed to solve the issue for me:

```
function runAutocomplete(element) {
 $(element).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                function: 'skuAutocomplete',
                data: {
                    skuAutocomplete: request
                }
           },
           error: function() {
              alert('An error occurred connecting to server. Please check your network');
           },
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(json) {
                if (json.status) {
                    response(json.data.skuAutocomplete);
                }else{
                    alert(json.message);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3
 });
}

runAutocomplete("#sku");
```